# WordPress исключение из вывода постов дочерних категорий

Tags: wordpress

Добавил свой тип записей, со своей систематикой. вывожу в archive.php

Вывожу в цикле так

```
<?php

    $cat = get_term_by('name', single_cat_title('',false), 'productscat'); 
 $catSlug = $cat->slug;
                        $args = array(
               'post_type' => 'products',
               'publish' => true,
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'productscat',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => $catSlug
                ),
              ),
           );

        query_posts($args);

    if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content-products', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;


    else :

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content-none', 'none' );

    endif;
wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Но, к сожалению, выводит и записи из дочерних категорий.

Подскажите, как мне запретить их вывод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите `'include_children' => false,` в массиве аргументов.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'publish'   => true,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'include_children' => false,
            'taxonomy'         => 'productscat',
            'field'            => 'slug',
            'terms'            => $catSlug,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Спасибо! кодекс надо мне учить.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.